# Extract and replace string with bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, grep

I have a string like: `func showFetchNextSliceFailed(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {`

From this, I would like to,

1). extract just `showFetchNextSliceFailed`

2). Insert it right above the given line, as `#Mark showFetchNextSliceFailed`.

```
  func showProductsList(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {    
  }      
  func showFetchNextSliceFailed(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {    
  }
```

**Expected output:**

```
  #Mark showProductsList
  func showProductsList(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {    
  }

  #Mark showFetchNextSliceFailed
  func showFetchNextSliceFailed(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {    
  }
```

I tried with `grep` and `sed`, but still can't figure out correctly how to extract and replace strings.

Comment: `tried with grep and sed` please add the attempts to question.. you should know by now that SO requires you to show(not tell) while asking :)

Comment: and don't cross-post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444276/extract-and-replace-string-with-bash

Comment: Did we answer your question?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short-order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Comment: Why are you using ``bash`` for this, instead of more powerful string processing languages like perl or python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed :

```
$ sed 's/\(.*func \)\([^ ]*\)\((.*\)/#Mark \2\n\1\2\3/' file.txt
```

If you want to replace in file :

```
$ sed -i 's/\(.*func \)\([^ ]*\)\((.*\)/#Mark \2\n\1\2\3/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the following `code` file:

**INPUT:**

```
  $more code
  func showProductsList(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {

  }

  func showFetchNextSliceFailed(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {

  }
```

**COMMAND:**

```
perl -i.bak -pe "s/^^( *|\t*)func\s(\w+)func\s(\w+)/\1#Mark \2\n\1func \2/g" code
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  #Mark showProductsList
  func showProductsList(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {

  }

  #Mark showFetchNextSliceFailed
  func showFetchNextSliceFailed(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {

  }
```

EXPLANATIONS:

- `-i.bak` in-place mode for `perl` with backup of the input file
- `s/^( *|\t*)func\s(\w+)func\s(\w+)/\1#Mark \2\n\1func \2/g` find and replace mode detailed at [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rV1zPs/1)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/\<func\s+([^(]+)\(/,a){print "#Mark", a[1]} 1' file
#Mark showProductsList
func showProductsList(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {
}
#Mark showFetchNextSliceFailed
func showFetchNextSliceFailed(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may also help you on same.

```
awk '/func/ && /showProductsList\(/{print "  #Mark showProductsList" ORS $0;next} /func/ && /showFetchNextSliceFailed\(/{print "  #Mark showFetchNextSliceFailed" ORS $0;next} 1'   Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
/func/ && /showProductsList\(/{
    print "  #Mark showProductsList" ORS $0;
    next}
/func/ && /showFetchNextSliceFailed\(/{
    print "  #Mark showFetchNextSliceFailed" ORS $0;
    next}
1
'   Input_file
```

In case you want to save the output into Input_file then you could append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` to above code too.

Answer (score -1):

Regex: `func\s(\w+)`

Replace with: `#Mark \1\n  func \1`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3BUL5r/1)